# Get at least last 2 rows from each row in a joined mysql 5.X tables

Tags: mysql, join, limit, sql-limit

I got two tables:

**Processes**

| idProcess | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | XXXX |
| 2 | XXXX |
| ... | ... |

**Tracings**:

| idTrace | idProcess |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

Need the last two idTrace from each idProcess ordered descending by idTrace:

| idTrace | idProcess |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| ... | ... |

**EDIT**
Can be rows in processes that does not exist in tracings yet...

Comment: Never use an `id` column to infer recency of a record. There are Many reasons that an id may be allocated out of sequence. An id is a surrogate key, it's Sole responsibility is to uniquely identify a row. Anything else is an anti-pattern. Always use another column such as a timestamp or other data for recording ordering.

Comment: Is this mysql 8 or 5.x?  They each have different approaches.

Comment: Is mysql 5.x, tracings has a timestamp colum, thanks for the observation!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your desired output shared in your question only has columns from your Tracings table you need not use a join but only include your Tracing table for efficiency.

**Schema (MySQL v5.5)**

The following approach uses variables to determine the order and a where clause to limit by the ordered row number.

```
SET @row_num:=0;
SET @prev_grp:=NULL;

SELECT
     t.idTrace,
     t.idProcess  
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        @row_num:=(
             CASE 
                 WHEN @prev_grp<>idProcess THEN 1
                 ELSE @row_num+1
             END
        ) as rn,
        @prev_grp:=idProcess
    FROM 
        Tracings
    ORDER BY 
        idProcess,idTrace DESC
) t 
WHERE rn <=2
ORDER BY t.idProcess,t.idTrace DESC;
```

or  as one query

```sql
SELECT
     t.idTrace,
     t.idProcess  
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        @row_num:=(
             CASE 
                 WHEN @prev_grp<>idProcess THEN 1
                 ELSE @row_num+1
             END
        ) as rn,
        @prev_grp:=idProcess
    FROM 
        Tracings
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num:=0,@prev_grp:=NULL) as vars 
    ORDER BY 
        idProcess,idTrace DESC
) t 

WHERE rn <=2
ORDER BY t.idProcess,t.idTrace DESC;
```

| idTrace | idProcess |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6xvXHYamMeJHa4AYzemgtD/3)

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

You may also use `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve this eg.

```
CREATE TABLE Processes (
  `idProcess` INTEGER,
  `data` VARCHAR(5)
);

INSERT INTO Processes
  (`idProcess`, `data`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'XXXX'),
  ('2', 'XXXXX');

CREATE TABLE Tracings (
  `idTrace` INTEGER,
  `idProcess` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Tracings
  (`idTrace`, `idProcess`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1'),
  ('2', '1'),
  ('3', '1'),
  ('4', '2'),
  ('5', '2'),
  ('6', '2'),
  ('7', '2');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
     idTrace,
     idProcess
FROM (
    SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY idProcess
             ORDER BY idTrace DESC
         ) rn
    FROM
        Tracings
) t
WHERE rn <=2
ORDER BY t.idProcess,t.idTrace DESC;
```

| idTrace | idProcess |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |

---

**Query #2 - if you require data from Processes table**

```
SELECT
     t.idTrace,
     t.idProcess,
     p.data
FROM 
Processes p 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY idProcess
             ORDER BY idTrace DESC
         ) rn
    FROM
        Tracings
) t ON p.idProcess = t.idProcess
WHERE rn <=2
ORDER BY t.idProcess,t.idTrace DESC;
```

| idTrace | idProcess | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | XXXX |
| 2 | 1 | XXXX |
| 7 | 2 | XXXXX |
| 6 | 2 | XXXXX |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6xvXHYamMeJHa4AYzemgtD/2)
Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: works perfect, but don't mention it has to be for mysql 5.x, sorry and thanks!!

Comment: @DiegoLaRosa I updated the answer with a similar approach that works with mysql 5.x and working demo db fiddle. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I noted that in a comment you mentioned that `tracings` had a timestamp column. You may modify the subquery of the mysql 5.x answer to `FROM 
        Tracings
    ORDER BY 
        idProcess,TimestampColumn DESC` to adjust for this.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL5.x could use a correlated sub query to find the rows you want to join on.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Processes   p
LEFT JOIN
  Tracings   t
    ON  t.idProcess = p.idProcess
    AND t.yourTimestampColumn >= (
      SELECT yourTimestampColumn 
        FROM Tracings
       WHERE idProcess = p.idProcess
    ORDER BY yourTimestampColumn DESC
       LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
    )
```

Demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q1YCHFwX3zLiZ6xd52TdN6/0

- Credit to @ggordon, who's demo I adopted

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in case that tracings has only one row for process i need at least that row. I test this in your fiddle and with one row in tracing by process shows nulls values.